# How to convert the GPS coordinates into x y position (Cartesian coordinates) for simulating drone?

Tags: python, python-2.7, gps

I have tried so many formulas for it but didn't get perfect formula for my output...

My GPS coordinates of my gazebo world of buildings are:

```
Building No.1  Latitude: 18.9990965928 , Longitude: 72.0000664814 , Altitude: 10.75        
Building No.2  Latitude: 18.9990965925 , Longitude: 71.9999050292 , Altitude: 22.2
Building No.3  Latitude: 18.9993675932 , Longitude: 72.0000569892 , Altitude: 10.7
```

I'm coding in python .
Give me correct formula for converting it to X,Y,Z coordinates...

Comment: The x, y and z coordinates should be on which projection plane? (Remember that the earth is not flat and also not perfectly round. That makes this kind of calculations rather complex.)

Comment: In my case + -0.2 error is acceptable..

Comment: Klaus D. is right that there are quite a few subtleties, so you need to give more information. Are you working with a package that handles conversions for you? What do you mean by "perfect formula" for your output? You should edit your post to include an example of code you've already tried and the output you've gotten to show us what's wrong.

Comment: The information in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4325545/355230) to another question may help.

Comment: @KartikGondhali..Do you want XYZ like in a horizontal plane? If so then this would be traditionally done by converting GPS positions to East North Up (or North East Down). So you can think of East == X, North == Y, and Up == Z (gravity-ish aligned). 
There is also XYZ positions on a sphere/ellipsoid (Cartesian/ECEF).